# BSOD when running Windows Defender

Tags: windows-8, bsod, windows-defender

I have recently installed Windows Phone 8 SDK on my Windows 8 Pro 64bit machine and I've been getting blue screen of death ever since. They show up every time my computer starts to be idle. The error I get is `attempted_execute_of_noexecute_memory`.

I noticed that the BSOD can be reproduced by launching Windows Defender and starting a scan.

Can anybody help me solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

Things I have already tried: blue screen viewer (shows the file responsible for the crash is ndis.sys, which is a windows file). I don't think the computer is infected, I run windows defender and it's up-to-date. I tried searching the web and my symptoms are exactly as those mentioned in [this forum](http://www.sysnative.com/forums/bsod-crashes-kernel-debugging/4869-attempted_execute_of_noexecute_memory-msmpeng-exe-windows-8-a-2.html), unfortunately there is no answer there.

And yes, I too have recently installed the Windows Phone 8 SDK with the Emulator, just like the person in the post, so I'm thinking that this could be related.

**EDIT2:**

I have tried chkdsk on both drives (HDD and SSD), it says that everything is OK.
I have tried sfc /scannow, it said that it found some corrupt files but was unable to fix them:
[image]

The log file it produced is [here](http://sdrv.ms/15CSv0S)).
The minidump from the last crash is [here](http://sdrv.ms/15CSoCE).
Windows update doesn't have any updated drivers for me.

**EDIT3:**

I turned on Driver Verifier as suggested by magicandre1981, but my computer started crashing right after boot. Here are two minidumps that got created:
[minidump1](http://sdrv.ms/19uYEov)
[minidump2](http://sdrv.ms/126X72k)

Thank you.
Jan

Comment: upload the .dmp files so that we can look at them with WinDbg

Comment: @magicandre1981 Uploaded the file. Check my updated original post for link.

Comment: the dump is not useful. Activate driver verifier (http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-16-WinDbg-Driver-Verifier), zip and upload the new memory.dmp from C:\Windows.

Comment: @magicandre1981 just added two more minidumps, see my original post

Comment: driver verifier found a HIDCLASS.SYS crash. So check for a new driver for your keyboard.

Comment: @magicandre1981 do you know which keyboard it is? This is a laptop computer, so there's one built in and I'm also using a wireless mouse+keyboard combo thru a USB dongle. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see which it is. update the drivers of your mouse/keyboard combo

Comment: @magicandre1981 did that, but it didn't help :-( Also tried downloading drivers for the built-in keyboard but the manufacturer (Acer) doesn't have any. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: did you get new crashes? if yes, upload the new dumps

Comment: @magicandre1981 here are the last two dumps: http://sdrv.ms/13wu891

Comment: dmp shows ndis.sys, but this is a Windows file

Answer (score 2):

The *`ATTEMPTED_EXECUTE_OF_NOEXECUTE_MEMORY`* bug check has a value of *`0x000000FC`*. This indicates that an attempt was made to execute non-executable memory. ([msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

To solve this problem, you can try:

- Check your hard disk for errors (like [chkdsk](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-scan-fix-hard-drives-with-chkdsk-in-windows-8/)).
- Download and install updates and device drivers for your computer from Windows Update.
- I do not know if it's applicable to your case or not, but you can try to do a scan [`sfc /scannow`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491008.aspx) to check the integrity of system files.

Comment: I have tried all of the above. Check my original post for links to results.

Answer (score 0):

It could be anything from a software conflict to a virus or spyware infection.
To understand better and help resolve it, please run a debugger like [Nirsoft blue screen viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluescreenview-x64.zip) and find out the exact error code & responsible file.

Comment: Edited my original post with answers to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the issue with the Windows Defender on Windows 8.0!
Lat 3/4 months everything was ok. Suddenly this started to happen.

I had to disable Windows Defender (the realtime protection) and also had to DisableAntiSpyware = 1 registery value in the registry under /Software/Microsoft/Windows Defender.

The problem doesn't happen anymore.

Note: To edit the registry value you have to change the ownership of the element first.